# ClearScript: how to get object values

Tags: clearscript

I have ClearScript that can do either

```
error = "value is invalid";
```

or

```
error = [
        {
            language: 'en',
            message: "value is invalid"
        },
        {
            language: 'fr',
            message: "valeur incorrecte"
        }
    ];
```

How, in C# can I get the values in the array?

And, to get either one case or the other I don't have a choice to do a try/catch, do I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your script sets up a global variable named `error` as shown above, you can process it like this:

```
dynamic error = engine.Script.error;
var message = error as string;
if (message != null) {
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
else if (error is ScriptObject) {
    if (error.constructor.name == "Array") {
        for (var i = 0; i < error.length; ++i) {
            Console.WriteLine("({0}) {1}", error[i].language, error[i].message);
        }
    }
    else {
        // handle other error types
    }
}
```

Comment: A lot less complicated than what I had tried. Thanks a lot.